# eBay GetMyeBaySelling API call not returning specified fields only

Tags: .net, performance, ebay-api, ebay-net-sdk

I use eBay SDK 921 API with sandbox.

I want to get all my Items IDs (I have a lot of items and I want improve the performance), and I use this code:

```
GetMyeBaySellingCall apicall = new GetMyeBaySellingCall(this.Context);
apicall.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);
apicall.ApiRequest.OutputSelector = new StringCollection(new string[] { "ItemID" });
apicall.GetMyeBaySelling();
var sellerlist = apicall.ActiveListReturn.ItemArray.ToArray();
```

but `GetMyeBaySelling` method returns all fields of the Items

Could you please help me to get the `ItemIDs` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the OutputSelector](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Basics/eBay-SelectingFields.html#WorkingwiththeOutputSelector) field states (emphasis added)

> You do not have to specify the full path of the field **unless the field you are specifying can be returned in multiple containers**.

Since `GetMyeBaySelling` returns several items the field `ItemID` will be returned in multiple containers. You will therefore have to specify the full path.

```
apicall.ApiRequest.OutputSelector = new StringCollection(new string[] { "ActiveList.ItemArray.Item.ItemID" });
```